# How to hide install new module link on http://localhost/admin/modules page?

Tags: users, hooks

I want to hide **install new module** link on http://localhost/admin/modules page?

I have created a new user role he/she have all admin rights(Editor Role), but I don't want to show **install new module** link to that user so that user should not be able to install any module in the website.

Comment: simply install redirect module when user visit this page redirect some where or you can do it by disable module permission under system

Comment: @adi!!!dear he should be able to see the list of available modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just remove the `Administer modules` permission under `System` for that role?

Answer (score 4):

Probably what you want is just to remove the permission **Administer software updates** from the role you mention. This way the user can still access the modules page, but won't be able to install new modules.

Comment: !!!This one is the perfect according to my requirement:)

Comment: This is good but it should be possible to remove it for the superuser also, on a platform or distribution level; a settings.php override perhaps.  It's simply not the recommended way to add modules (use Composer!) so it shouldn't be shown even to user 1.